# Get date and create a start and finish value in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to be able to set this start date to the beginning of the day i.e. 03/04/2023 12AM, and the end date to the end of the day i.e. 03/04/2023 11:59 PM without explicitly hard-coding the time, like I have below.

Is there a way to achieve this?

```
$date   = '03/04/2023';
$start  = strtotime($date . ' ' . '07:00');
$finish = strtotime($date . ' ' . '20:00');
```

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: The end of the day is not 23:59. 60 seconds are missing until the end of the day. The end of one day is the beginning of the next day. So there is no gap from one day to the next. Please reconsider your question.